# Where are the default slot colors defined for jquery fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm working on a solution where JQuery full calendar is used.

I need to know the default color used in this calendar for empty slots.

I searched all the solution for fc-widget-content, fc-time-grid, fc-slats and many other classes trying to figure out where the slot color is defined.

But I can't find it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've just tried it. I can't find it, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After returning back to our UI designer and some investigation, I found the default color for the slots is defined in fullcalendar.css and the class name is .fc-state-default.